# Using Jquery to get a CSS Property in an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe (which is part of my site)

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="/../index.php"></iframe>
```

Using JQuery I know I can change a CSS property in the iframe, such as color:

```
$('#iframeID').load(function(){
    $("#iframeID").contents().find('body').css('color','#FC0');
});
```

But I want to **get a css property in the iframe**, I tired lots of things such as:

```
$('#iframeID').load(function(){
    $color = $("#iframeID").contents().find('body').css('color');
});
```

But I can't figure it out.

Comment: just curious, though might not be related to the actual query in hand... the CSS property you wish to retrieve from body of the iframe content is the `color` (as in text color) and not something like `background-color` ?

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KMxqe/1/

Comment: I actually want to be able to get any CSS property from any tag, class or ID in the iframe. Getting the color was just an example.  And I feel like this should be so easy to do, like $('.someiframeCLASS').css('font-size').  In firebug I can see all the CSS properties of the iframe - just taunting me.

Comment: Have you tried attr('style',...?

Comment: **Actually, the code works in Safari and Explorer.** Just not for me in firefox.  **But** the jsfiddle from Sheikh works for me in my firefox.  So I'm thinking its something else that i am doing is my jQuery code. I'll post when I find.  Thanks all.

Comment: **My Problem** - I had a fadeTo() on the iframe, hence it was not loaded when I tried to get the CSS property.  Everything is perfect.  **Anyway, this is a way to get properties in an iframe, so I'm sure some will find it helpful.**